# macro: copy paste cell if condition met

Tags: vba, excel

There’s one step that’s stuck, to update the stock number (column "D") in the database_ gudang (stock in the database_ gudang is added to the amount of receipt (column "K") from form_penerimaan)

The update is based on the name of the item (nama barang), so if the name of the item (column "C") in the form_penerimaan is the same as the name of the item (column "B") in the database_ gudang, the stock in database_ gudang will be updated.

but there’s  a problem, which is updated only in rows 2,9,10 (yellow cell). A row of 3,4,5 should also be updated.

Thank you very much for your help.

Regards.

```
Sub Module1()
    s = 10
    OT1 = Sheets("Database_Gudang").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

    For j = 2 To OT1
        NB1 = Sheets("Database_Gudang").Cells(j, "B").Value

        Sheets("Form_Penerimaan").Activate
        If Cells(s, "C").Value = NB1 And Cells(s, "C").Value <> "" Then
            Sheets("Form_Penerimaan").Cells(s, "Q").Copy

            Sheets("Database_Gudang").Activate
            Sheets("Database_Gudang").Cells(j, "G").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

            s = s + 1
        End If
    Next j
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi and Welcome to stackoverflow :)

Avoid the use of `.Select` and `.Activate`. Directly work with variables and objects. You may want to see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

You are facing that issue because you are not looping through the cells of the 2nd sheet.

Is this what you are trying? (**UNTESTED**)

I have commented the code so you may not have a problem in understanding it. If you do then share the exact error message and we will take it from there.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wsThis As Worksheet, wsThat As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim wsThisLRow As Long, wsThatLRow As Long

    '~~> Set your worksheets
    Set wsThis = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database_Gudang")
    Set wsThat = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Form_Penerimaan")

    '~~> Find relevant last row in both sheets
    wsThisLRow = wsThis.Range("D" & wsThis.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    wsThatLRow = wsThat.Range("C" & wsThat.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With wsThis
        '~~> Loop through cell in Database_Gudang
        For i = 2 To wsThisLRow
            '~~> Loop through cell in Form_Penerimaan
            For j = 10 To wsThatLRow
                '~~> Compare values and get values across if applicable
                If .Range("B" & i).Value = wsThat.Range("C" & j).Value Then
                    .Range("G" & i).Value = wsThat.Range("Q" & j).Value
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you Siddharth, it's working. thank you very  much